# jQuery function optimization

Tags: jquery, performance

Is there a way to make this faster?

This function manages some dynamic form elements.

```
 function HideAllDivs(parentDiv) {
        var divs = $('#' + parentDiv + ' div'), divsLength = divs.length;   
        for (var a = 0; a < divsLength; a++) {
            var obj = $('#' + divs[a].id);
            obj.find('input[type=radio]:checked').removeProp('checked');
            obj.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeProp('checked');
            obj.find('input[type=text]').val('');
            obj.find('select').val('');
            obj.find('input[type=radio]').each(function () { $(this).removeClass('selectedCtrl');   });
            obj.hide(1);                           
        }    
    }
```

Thanks,
David

Comment: Isn't `var obj = $('#' + divs[a].id);` the same as saying `var obj = $(divs[a]);` ?

Comment: I think the best way to optimize this is to convert it to pure JS

Comment: Question. in the variable divs, you have $('#' + parentDiv + ' div') , does this mean you have multiple divs with the same ID on the page and you are trying to iterate through them? That's what it looks like and it's invalid html, ID's should always be unique.

Comment: @DanielWard It looks to me like he *doesn't* have divs with the same ID, which is why he has a variable in there

Comment: +1 for an interesting question

Comment: This code can be optimize but I don't think you will get a huge performance improvements unless you have a really really really big form ;)

Comment: The fact that he is calling the function HideAllDivs, using a variable named divs, and is using a loop, for some odd reason made me think he was using multiple elements with the same id, but you are correct. The function only works on the one target div. Now I feel silly for missing that. ;)

Comment: About 70  divs with the controls inside a container div. Thanks, you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can speed it up (slightly) by using..

```
function HideAllDivs(parentDiv) {
    $('#' + parentDiv + ' div')
        .hide()
        .find('input, select')
            .removeProp(':checked') // will be ignored where not applicable
            .removeClass('selectedCtrl') // will be ignored where not applicable
            .filter('input[type="text"], select').val('');
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting the original poster's code and comment made it appear that there were restraints... ie: If you have a `input[type=text].selectedCtrl` that you do _not_ want to remove the class from, techfoobar's code fails... but his is extremely fast if you do not have to worry about such constraints :)   added it to: http://jsperf.com/hiding-divs-19362135

Comment: Only the radio buttons have the 'selectedCtrl' class... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a loop and you can improve the 2 operations using radio buttons

```
function HideAllDivs(parentDiv) {
    var divs = $('#' + parentDiv + ' div');

    var radios = divs.find('input[type=radio]')
    radios.filter(':checked').removeProp('checked');
    radios.find('.selectedCtrl').removeClass('selectedCtrl');

    divs.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeProp('checked');
    divs.find('input[type=text], select').val('');
    divs.hide(1);
}
```

Comment: Not that I doubt you, but could you elaborate on how this makes the function faster?  I would think finding each unique id and iterating through the results seems more efficient than having to run .find() on the set of divs selected from jQ...but that just may be my ignorance on how .find() works :P

Comment: Why do you filter for ':checked' if you remove checked anyway

Comment: when you say `this.find()`, there is a iteration happening from jQuery... so in OP's case the iteration is happening 2n times instead of n

Comment: I see, so couldn't he essentially remove the .find()'s and leave his original iteration, using selectors instead?

Comment: @jantimon that one need to be profiled.... whether trying to remove a non existent property is costlier or filtering it

Answer (score 0):

I thought this should be slightly faster...

```
function HideAllDivs(parentDiv) {

  var $divs = $('#' + parentDiv + ' div');

  $divs
    .find('input[type=text],select').val('').end()
    .find(':checked').removeProp('checked').end()
    .find('.selectedCtrl[type=radio]').removeClass('selectedCtrl').end()
    .hide(1);
}
```

Performance tests below
*** Edit: Fail, I didn't actually run the tests -_-; fixed.***
http://jsperf.com/hiding-divs-19362135

Comment: Shrink if you're looking for a succinct code, mine is fairly pretty and readable, but check the tests... what I thought was fast is actually slow... even as a fairly experienced jQuery dev I'm struggling to understand why, but JSPerf doesn't lie.

Comment: Again, I failed in the test, I was running the code from the point of view of our answers, not taking into account your original code was using the `id`s , it turns out mine is fairly fast, but there's a faster one. It's up to which you chose... there's trade off between readability and speed